# What sorts of strings are legal inputs to C string functions?

Tags: c, string

Do functions like `strcat` and `strcmp` require null-terminated strings as arguments, or is any array of characters acceptable ?

All documentations suggest it must be null-terminated, but one of the most well known online references (http://cplusplus.com) gives the following as example of `strcmp`:

```
/* strcmp example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char szKey[] = "apple";
  char szInput[80];
  do {
     printf ("Guess my favourite fruit? ");
     gets (szInput);
  } while (strcmp (szKey,szInput) != 0);
  puts ("Correct answer!");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://cplusplus.com is not C. It's C++. Doesn't matter here, but important to remember.

Comment: @Dan: That code is pure C. It should compile as C++  as well, but there's nothing unique to C++ in it at all.

Comment: I realize that, which is why it doesn't matter, but it's important to understand that there's a difference between the two languages and I wasn't sure that this user did.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the functions required null-terminated strings.  However, the example you've listed above does indeed use null-terminated strings.  For example, the line

```
char szKey[] = "apple";
```

Describes a string that has a null terminator appended, even though it's not immediately apparent in the source code.  Any string literal in C is automatically null-terminated, even if you don't explicitly put the request in yourself (though there is an exception, as we'll see in a minute).

Moreover, in the line

```
gets (szInput);
```

The function `gets` automatically appends a null-terminator to the end of the string that it reads from the console.  In fact, with few exceptions (such as the notoriously complex `strncat` function), all string manipulation functions in `<string.h>` automatically append a null-terminator.  It is rare in common usage to end up with a non-null-terminated string unless you're explicitly messing around with the character bytes yourself.

That said, there are many ways to get strings that aren't null-terminated.  For example, if you define a string like this:

```
char hello[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}; /* Careful! */
```

This array will not be null-terminated, because you've explicitly listed off the values you'd like it to have.  This means that what you have is an array of characters rather than a string.  If you then tried calling

```
printf("%s\n", hello);
```

You would run into undefined behavior because the array is not null-terminated.

Additionally, if you use any of the raw memory manipulation routines like `memcpy` or `memmove`, then you need to be careful to ensure that the null terminator is copied or set explicitly, since these routines have no concept of null-terminators.

Also, one quick bit of terminology - `NULL` usually refers to a null *pointer*, that is, a pointer that is explicitly marked as pointing to no object.  The null in null-terminator refers to the character with numeric value 0 and is a character (not a pointer) used to indicate that the end of a string has been reached.  While the names are the same (and there are similarities), it's best not to confuse the two.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @JerryCoffin- Yes, that was the intent.  I'll clarify that it isn't a string.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

`gets()` does null-terminate, and `szKey[] = "apple";` is null-terminated. `"apple"` is a string literal which is always null terminated.

`strcmp` requires the string to copy to have a `\0` terminator otherwise it could possibly run off the end of the string and cause access violations.

`strcat` also requires its arguments to be `\0` terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Strings need to be NUL terminated, but I don't see any problem with NUL termination in that code.

I should add that this is nearly the *only* problem it doesn't have. Using `gets`, in particular, is inexcusable.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a string is always NULL-terminated.

`"apple"` gets actually treated as `apple\0` by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely they must be null terminated.

Comparison functions like strcmp must have something to stop the comparison and that is the null character.

There are other functions like strncmp which take a length parameter. In this case strings do not have to be null terminated as you provide the number of characters to compare.

Answer (score 0):

They have to be NULL-terminated, because the length is unknown. The way the library functions work is they start at the beginning of a string, and iterate through every character until the null byte is encountered. If this isn't the case, the function will continue on into memory where it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think those /aren't/ null-terminated? String literals are automatically null terminated, and (provided that there's enough space in the buffer) gets() will also null-terminate.

That point there - that gets will only null-terminate if there's space in the buffer - is the reason you should use getsn() instead of gets().

Comment: Which platform provides `getsn()`?

Comment: Probably gcc has it. `fgets()` is the ANSI C standard function that allows a maximum length.

Comment: What's the prototype for `getsn()`? my first few guesses didn't compile under gcc.

Comment: It would appear that I was making stuff up. The only references I can find are Texas Instruments and BSD. fgets(buffer, size, stdin) seems to be the correct thing.